# Couting items and grouping them by levels

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework 6 and I have the following Linq Query:

```
  IDictionary<BodyMassIndexLevel, Int32> bmistats = 
    context.Evaluations

    // Get all evaluations where Height and Weight measures were done
    .Where(x => x.Height != null && x.Weight != null)

    // Select the date of the evaluation, the worker id and calculate BMI
    .Select(x => new { Date = x.Date, Worker = x.Worker.Id, BMI = x.Weight.Value / Math.Pow(x.Height.Value / 100, 2) })

    // Group by worker
    .GroupBy(x => x.Worker)

    // Get the most recent evaluation for each worker and so the most recent BMI
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).Select(y => new { BMI = y.BMI }).FirstOrDefault())

    // Cache the result in memory
    .ToList()

    // Count the number of BMIS in each level
    .With(z =>
      new Dictionary<BodyMassIndexLevel, Int32> {
        { BodyMassIndexLevel.SevereThinness, z.Count(w => w.BMI < 16) },
        { BodyMassIndexLevel.MildThinness, z.Count(w => w.BMI >= 16 && w.BMI < 17) },
        { BodyMassIndexLevel.ModerateThinness, z.Count(w => w.BMI >= 17 && w.BMI < 18.5) },
        { BodyMassIndexLevel.Normal, z.Count(w => w.BMI >= 18.5 && w.BMI < 25) },
        { BodyMassIndexLevel.PreObese, z.Count(w => w.BMI >= 25 && w.BMI < 30) },
        { BodyMassIndexLevel.ObeseClassI, z.Count(w => w.BMI >= 30 && w.BMI < 35) },
        { BodyMassIndexLevel.ObeseClassII, z.Count(w => w.BMI >= 35 && w.BMI < 40) },
        { BodyMassIndexLevel.ObeseClassIII, z.Count(w => w.BMI >= 40) }
      }
    );
```

I have two questions:

1. Is is possible to improve the performance of this query?
2. Can I move the Count part in levels to the query and so having not ToList()?

Answer (score 0):

For example

1. Make something like Truncate for BMI after 
   *// Select the date of the evaluation, the worker id and calculate BMI*
2. Create *BMILevel* table with columns *(BMILevelName | BMIValues)* containing rows like *(BodyMassIndexLevel.ModerateThinness, 17), (BodyMassIndexLevel.PreObese, 25), (BodyMassIndexLevel.PreObese, 26), etc*.
3. `JOIN your select query with *BMILevel* table on query.BMI = BMILevel.BMIValue`, than `GroupBy BMILevel.BMILevelName` and finally `Count` for all groups.

Alternatively you may define *BMILevel* with columns *(BMILevelName | BMIValueBeginInterval, BMIValueEndInterval)* containing rows like *(BodyMassIndexLevel.ModerateThinness, 17, 18), (BodyMassIndexLevel.PreObese, 25, 30)*.

And thus perform

```
query JOIN BMILevel ON query.BMI BETWEEN BMILevel.BMIValueBeginInterval AND BMILevel.BMIValueEndInterval
```

I consider EF can transform '<', '&&', '>' within .Where() (or Join) call  properly

---

### **UPDATE:**

If you don't want to create another one table, you may try create in-memory list of objects of sample type

```
class BMILevel {
   public BMILevelEnum BMILevelName {get;set;}
   public double BMILevelValueBeginInterval {get;set;}
   public double BMILevelValueEndInterval {get;set;}
}
```

than create in-memory collection:

```
var bmiLevels = new List<BMILevel> { new BMILevel {...}, ... }
```

and use it in the way I describe it above.
I don't know how good EF 6 is, but old versions were unable to handle operations with non-entities (it couldn't translate expressions to proper SQL) and thus it results in inefficient querying or errors.

The only way to perform your query faster is to delegate it to SQL server. You can use EF abilities and thus it's possible that it requires of the creation of a new table. Another way - use ADO.NET (SqlCommand, SqlConnection, etc) and do it bypassing EF.

Comment: Sorry, could you give me an example for (1)? I am not sure what you mean. About the rest I would like to avoid creating a table for BMILevels in my database.

Comment: I mean .Select(x => new { Date = x.Date, Worker = x.Worker.Id, BMI = Math.Truncate(x.Weight.Value / Math.Pow(x.Height.Value / 100, 2)) }), but it's just a way to make join on equality. But it still requires to create new table in database.